# Google Sheets conditional formatting with AND function not working

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am hoping that you can help me out with a google sheets conditional formatting error. I am trying to combine the below formulas with the and function. Separately they work. But combined they do not.

Any help would be great. I have been struggling with this simple formula for too long!

Thanks

Separate formulas:

=($A111<>"")
=(isblank($F111))

COMBINED:

=AND((isblank($F111)), ($A111<>""))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing extra parenthesis:

```
=AND(isblank($F111),$A111<>"")
```

Changing locale, commas with semi-colons:

```
=AND(isblank($F111);$A111<>"")
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but am getting an "Invalid formula" error. Its really bizarre

Comment: Maybe the locale, changing comma with semicolons? `=AND(isblank($F111);$A111<>"")`

Comment: I'm glad! Consider marking the question as answered ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
=(isblank($F111))*($A111<>"")
```